# Translate a Pandas df using googletrans, AttributeError error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-translate

I am trying to translate words from a Pandas dataframe column and get error in googletrans.Translator() class. It works normal with single words or phrases. Can it be environmental issue?

Any help or suggestions much appreciated

```
import pandas as pd 
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()

df = pd.DataFrame({'Spanish':['piso','cama']})
df['English'] = df['Spanish'].apply(translator.translate, src='es', dest='en').apply(getattr, args=('text',))
```

Output:

```
AttributeError: 'Translator' object has no attribute 'raise_Exception'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi this error occured because there is an exception occurred in the runtime. To see the error insert this below code

`python translator.raise_Exception = True` 
If you get the error as below

`Exception: Unexpected status code "429" from ['translate.google.com']`

which means Too many requests. Hope you would not get this error. If so you have to upgrade you account. To avoid the error please refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41618773/10583434)

[Source 1](https://support.google.com/translate/thread/15027713?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks, but yes, now I`m getting 429, trying to fix this)

Comment: You are welcome. I have attached a possible fix also in the answer.Can you please accept my answer.